# Where are the private lists stored when you are saving lists in "My Lists"

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Where are the private lists stored when you are saving lists in "My Lists"?

Found this explenation:

"User profile pictures are stored in the My Site Host site collection. The My Site Host site collection is created from the SPSMSITEHOST#0 template. When the SharePoint Online tenant is provisioned, a My Site Host site collection is created. The profile pictures are stored in a document library that's named "User Photos." The pictures are stored in a folder inside the User Photo document library by having a .jpg filename extension".

But how can i access My Site?

Greetings, P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Lists are stored in your personal site. These are good old SharePoint lists, in a good old SharePoint site.

You can verify it by navigating your the MS List service and then replacing `/Lists.aspx` with `/ViewLsts.aspx` in the URL:

[image]